# Code first foreign keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, code-first

Within my view, I need to return FullName for every Initiator and Owner. To do so, should both Initiator and Owner be foreign keys of EmployeeID?

I'm not sure how to make both Initiator and Owner foreign keys using code first nor how to display FullName using razor.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**ChangeRequest**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class ChangeRequest
    {
        public int ChangeRequestID { get; set; }
        public int Initiator { get; set; }
        public int Owner { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return Surname + ", " + FirstName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ChangeRequests)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Initiator)
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned EF version, if you want lazy loading, or if you are using attributes or Fluent api, so here's a good reference for Many-Valued Assocations [using Fluent API](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx) and one using [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx), and a bit of example code making some assumptions about version, lazy loading and attributes:

```
public class ChangeRequest
{
    [Key]
    public int ChangeRequestID { get; set; }
    public int? InitiatorId { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("InitiatorId")]
    public virtual Employee Initiator { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual Employee Owner { get; set; }
}
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Initiator")]
    public virtual ICollection<ChangeRequest> CrsInitiated { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Owner")]
    public virtual ICollection<ChangeRequest> CrsOwned { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return Surname + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Razor:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ChangeRequests)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Initiator.FullName)
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner.FullName)
}
```